# Creating a text program

Tags: text-editor

i have a feeling that this question doesn't fit here, so if that is true, please just ignore it, sorry for the cluttering.

I can't find any information about how one would go about making a text editing program, like the field this post is written in. Im not asking how massive programs like word work, but just the basics like the windows notepad. I believe the reason for this, is because the only term i know of these programs is text editors, but these seem to refer to complicated text editors.

I would really apreaciate if someone could point me to a resource discussing this, or give some advice. Sorry for the amateur question.

Answer (score 0):

C or C++ will be a good language to create a text editor program. With these languages you can build your own text editor.

Go through these links to get completely detailed idea to build text editors in c or c++

- https://viewsourcecode.org/snaptoken/kilo/
- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/237508/How-To-Build-A-Simple-Text-Editor-A-Tutorial